# How to add attribute to class before __init__?

Tags: python, attributes, initialization

**Question**

I have a Python module that creates instances of many other modules at runtime.  The other modules are specified via an external configuration file, which also houses all arguments/values for each module's `__init__`.

I would like to add the same attribute to all new instances, but I don't want to add a new arg to `__init__` on all of my classes.  How can I go about this?

**My Thoughts**

One possible solution: on the fly, I can add a new arg to `__init__` by somehow manipulating the `__init__` attribute on the module.  Then I can pass it the attribute I want to add on all instances.

I am pretty sure this violates the Zen of Python.  That being said, I am curious how one could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the `**kwargs` `__init__` parameter and use `__setattr__` to automatically set any new passed parameter.
Example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            self.__setattr__(key, kwargs[key])
```

You would only have to blindly add these two lines plus the **kwargs argument to your classes, then:

```
f = Foo(name="bar")
print(f.name)
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Comment: that is not a bad option.  Thank you for giving me a great idea! :)